# Android Studio, How can I fill a custom ListView with data from an array or cursor?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, textview, android-arrayadapter

So I have a fragment view that looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    //Various elements

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/notes_list_view"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

So the listview is at the bottom of a set of elements. I have been trying to figure out how to fill items in this listview, but no matter what I try I can't get anything to appear in the array, it's empty every time.  Ideally I'd like to fill a item view that looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_1_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_2_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_3_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_4_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone help me with writing an ArrayAdapter or CursorAdapter to just make something appear, I can tweak it later, which I plan on doing anyway since the data will ultimately come from a database.

Alternatively, can someone find what is causing nothing to display, I am not experienced in UI design, and I am worried I simply have the space for the listview obstructed.

For reference, I am using a min SDK of 11.

Comment: with `SimpleCursorAdapter` you dont need to write anything but the adapter's constructor (also no need to iterate over the db `Cursor`), and please **DON'T** use `ArrayAdapter` like in answer you accepted, it is **NOT** the way you should follow if your data comes from sqlite db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a Data transfer Class to store the Values Required to populate

```
public class Item
{
 public string text1,text2,text3,text4;
 public byte[] image;
}
```

Set values from Db into `ArrayList` of `Item`,then in Adpater Using `DataDto` fill the View as in

```
    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

     ArrayList<Item> p;
        public ListAdapter(Context ArrayList<Item> items) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, items);
            p=items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi;
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }



            if (p != null) {
                TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_1_textview);
                TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_2_textview);
                TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_3_textview);
                TextView tt4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_4_textview);
                ImageView img=(ImageView)
v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
                if (tt1 != null) {
                    tt1.setText(p.get(position).text1);
                }

                if (tt2 != null) {
                    tt2.setText(p.get(position).text4);
                }

                if (tt3 != null) {
                    tt3.setText(p.get(position).text3);
                }
                if (tt4 != null) {
                    tt1.setText(p.get(position).text4);
                }
               if(img!=null)
               {
                byte[] bitmapdata =p.get(position).image;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
                  img.setimageBitmap(bitmap);
               }

            }

            return v;
        }

    }
```

in your Activity ,fill ArrayList and pass it to Adapter as in

```
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.notes_list_view);
ArrayList<Item> items; populate this list from DB
ListAdpater data=new ListAdapter(this,items);
lv.setAdapter(data);
```